# Possible order of evaluation difference in Mono vs. .NET

Tags: mono, protobuf-net

I have a Equals override on a object to check for value equality between two objects deserialized using a precompiled protobuf-net serialiser object. I have verified that the deserialisation occurs as expected (on that note, protobuf-net is awesome).

This class is very simple, but an equivalent problem occurs with other, more complex ones, so I'll use this as the model.

Here is the code fragment in question:

```
public bool Equals (CompressionConfiguration other) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
return string.Equals (AlgorithmName, other.AlgorithmName) &&
        (AlgorithmConfiguration == null ? other.AlgorithmConfiguration == null : 
        AlgorithmConfiguration.SequenceEqual(other.AlgorithmConfiguration));
}
```

When executed under the .NET runtime, this evaluates as expected, allowing a null value for AlgorithmConfiguration, which is of byte[] type. Under Mono, I get a SequenceEqual null parameter error, specifically a ArgumentNullException. What gives? This shouldn't happen because SequenceEqual should only be called if AlgorithmConfiguration != null.

This is definitely the source because if I supply a zero-length byte[] for CompressionConfiguration no failure occurs. I'd really rather not send zero-length arrays if possible.
I have to have Mono compatibility because this is to be used on Xamarin.Android (MonoDroid) and MonoTouch, as well in a Mono server, and then .NET desktop applications.

Comment: It looks like AlgorithmConfiguration is not null and other.AlgorithmConfiguration is null. That will get past all your checks.

Comment: It's the same object - and AlgorithmConfiguration is definitely null. That's a good point though, thanks! I'll add that case in.
Also, I just recompiled the serialiser, and now it works perfectly. I am puzzled. I have not changed anything... Anyway, it works now. Perhaps the precompiled serialiser must be recompiled for use under Mono using the Mono compiler - I think it was using a dll compiled on my Windows machine. It worked the other way around!

Comment: If it was the same object, the "this" check would catch it

Comment: Sorry, when I say same I mean "has value equality", not "has same reference"

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, recompiling the serialiser assembly under Mono resolved the issue, even though this is not the origin of the ArgumentNullException, and I had verified the objects had deserialised properly. Everything works now.

Comment: That's just... bizarre! when you say "recompiling the serialiser assembly"... which assembly specifically? Is there anything I can do to repro this?

Comment: I have a solution we'll call MySolution. I have a project under that using a namespace MyProject.DTO, which contains all the serialisable data objects. I was using protobuf-net's precompile.exe to generate a serialiser assembly of type MySolution.DTOSerialiser. DTOSerialiser is the one I recompiled. I didn't recompile the MySolution.DTO project, or MySolution.Tests. All tests worked under Windows, but not under OS X with Mono.